# Second dataset result not showing on first time execution

Tags: reporting-services

I had created a SSRS reports where it generates list of studnts with selected subjects and it marks which was displayed in matrix successfully. After that I need to tshow the overall analysis of each subject in the same report.
So I had created total 2 procedures.

First one for dataset 1 list of students with respective subject wise marks.
As like temp table here I had created a table where I push the analysis of each subject in the new table.

And by using the second procedure for dataset 2 I planned for fetching the data of subject wise analysis.

Every time the second proc executes I'm deleting the data of that table.

My problem is I'm not getting the data from dataset 2 on the firt execution.From the second run I'm able to get the data.
Whenever I had changed the parameters for the first time It's not geting the data.

```
    ALTER Proc [dbo].[SP_Get_IGCSESubjectMarks_GetLastTerm_HTS2] --7,'1,17,8','2537,2555,2558,2568'
(

@ReportId int=7,
@SubjectId varchar(200),
@SectionId varchar(200)
)
AS
BEGIN
-------------------
------------------- Some code

Insert into #temp (Name,Class,SubjectName,Section,enrollNo,TermName,TestName,Marks)
select Name,Class,'Total',Section,enrollNo,TermName,'Percentage',SUM(Marks)*100/sum(maxmarksare) from #temp1 
GROUP BY Name,Class,Section,enrollNo,SubjectName,TermName,SubjectOrder

--TmpIgcseData is the new table for which I'm pushing the subject wise analysis This was the table used in 2nd dataset for fetching data.
delete  from  TmpIgcseData
insert into TmpIgcseData(enrollno,SName,SubjectName,TestName,Marks,OrderNumber) select  enrollno,Name,SubjectName,TestName,Marks,SubjectOrder from #temp



select @UID as Id,* from #temp
drop table #temp
drop table #temp1

end

--------------------------------------------------------------

ALTER PROC [dbo].[IgcesResultAnalysis_HTS2]
AS
begin
------------
------------ Some code.
select * from #distsubjects
--Deleting the data from the table
delete  from  TmpIgcseData

End
```

[image: Image view of my SSRS report]

Answer (score 0):

This is really bad practice. You are editing data in a permanent table (TmpIgcseData). What happens if two people execute the report? You also cannot rely on the execution order of the datasets in SSRS.

It is much better to pass the required parameters to both procedures and do all the work within each procedure. In other words, do not rely on another proc to prepare the data unless you call that proc from with your main proc and restrict the tables used to temp tables within the scope of the main proc.